# Cómo parsear una fecha y mandarla a una lista

Tags: android, date, recyclerview, adapter

Este es mi adaptador, en el `holder` estoy haciendo el parseo, pero cuando ejecutola aplicación, ésta se me detiene.

```
public class Adaptador extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.AdapaterViewHolder> {

    private List<Agenda>lista;
    private Context mainContext;
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    public Adaptador(List<Agenda>lista ){

        this.lista=lista;
        this.formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    }


    @Override
    public AdapaterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
        return  new AdapaterViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapaterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //datos que voy a mostrar

        holder.tipo_solicitud.setText(lista.get(position).getTipo_solicitud());
        holder.tipo_traslado.setText(lista.get(position).getTipo_traslado());

        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(lista.get(position).getFecha_cita());
            String fecha = date.toString();
            holder.fecha_cita.setText(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder. identificacion.setText(lista.get(position).getIdentificacion());
        holder. nombre.setText(lista.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.fecha_nacimiento.setText(lista.get(position).getFecha_nacimiento());
        holder.entidad_eps.setText(lista.get(position).getEntidad_eps());
        holder. lugar_recoger.setText(lista.get(position).getLugar_recoger());
        holder. departamento_recoge.setText(lista.get(position).getDepartamento_recoge());
        holder. ciudad_recoge.setText(lista.get(position).getCiudad_recoge());
        holder.medico_recibe.setText(lista.get(position).getMedico_recibe());
        holder.lugar_destino.setText(lista.get(position).getMedico_recibe());
        holder.departamento_destino.setText(lista.get(position).getLugar_destino());
        holder. diagnostico.setText(lista.get(position).getDiagnostico());
        holder.soportes_vitales.setText(lista.get(position).getSoportes_vitales());
        holder.observaciones.setText(lista.get(position).getObservaciones());

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return lista.size();
    }


    public class AdapaterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView tipo_solicitud;
        TextView tipo_traslado;
        TextView fecha_cita;
        TextView identificacion;
        TextView nombre;
        TextView fecha_nacimiento;
        TextView entidad_eps;
        TextView lugar_recoger;
        TextView departamento_recoge;
        TextView ciudad_recoge;
        TextView medico_recibe;
        TextView lugar_destino;
        TextView departamento_destino;
        TextView diagnostico;
        TextView soportes_vitales;
        TextView observaciones;


        public AdapaterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tipo_solicitud = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTipo_solictud);
             tipo_traslado =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTipo_traslado);


            fecha_cita= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha_solicitud);
              identificacion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIdentificacion);
             nombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombre_paciente);
             fecha_nacimiento= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha_Nacimiento);
             entidad_eps= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEndidad_eps);
            lugar_recoger= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLugar_recoger);
             departamento_recoge= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepartamento);
             ciudad_recoge= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCiudad_recoge);
             medico_recibe= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMedico_Recibe);
             lugar_destino= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLugar_destino);
             departamento_destino= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepartamento_destino);
             diagnostico= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDiagnostico);
             soportes_vitales= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSoportes_vitales);
             observaciones= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvObservacion);
```

Comment: Hola Briyith, bienvenida a StackOverflow. La pregunta está bien, pero necesitas dar más detalles para que las personas interesadas en asistirte puedan hacerlo efectivamente. Agrega detalles como *qué muestra la consola del IDE*, *si hay errores, cuáles son*, etc.

Comment: ... y en qué parte del código se detiene, qué hiciste para depurarlo, qué valores están asignados en las variables que entran en juego donde está fallando... ayudanos a ayudarte